# Can I have a generic method in a injectable class?

Tags: angular, dart, angular2-dart

Like:

```
@Injectable()
class ApiService {
  Future<T> fetch<T>(String path) {
    ...
  }
}
```

this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was fixed within the analyzer package 0.29:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/CHANGELOG.md

However, if you do:

```
T aa<T>() { 
  print(T.toString());
}
```

you will get a "dynamic" instead of the original class, which, very unfortunately, doesn't help me

Answer (score 4):

Seems this was fixed very recently and is probably not yet included in the latest 3.0.0-alpha+1

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/issues/266

Comment: Gunter, do you know when we will have runtime info with generics methods? or the git issue so I can subscribe please

Comment: I don't think there are concrete plans. Perhaps with or after Dart 2.0